# Starred version of command does not compile

Tags: equations, align

I use the following command from the [mathtools manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf), p.29 together with the huge [thesis-template](https://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/templates/thesis/) from Matthias Pospiech.

```latex
\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode‘\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brkts()
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\brkts{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}
    }
```

In a stand-alone document, the command works fine but within the thesis template, the starred version causes the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.115 $\brkts*{a}
                 $
? error: cannot find startxref
warning: trying to repair broken xref
warning: repairing PDF document
warning: object missing 'endobj' token
```

Any ideas on what might cause this? I don't want to bisect everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Use

```
\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
```

it is `` ` `` (ascii char) not `‘` which is some unicode char.

Comment: How on earth did this happen?! THANK YOU!

Comment: Argh... the vim plugin `Yggdroot/indentLine` renders `\`` as `‘` and I copy-pasted it from vim. 

Comment: @Suuuehgi there are other editor who think they are clever, or even pdf viewers